# Grails Gradle Docker Plugin bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/ throws Could not set unknown property 'env'

Tags: docker, gradle, grails

```
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not set unknown property 'env' for task ':createPostgresContainer' of type com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerCreateContainer. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/

I was using this Gradle Docker Plugin to setup a Postgres docker container to test out some database related stuff on the Mac, by following the example here. http://guides.grails.org/grails-docker-external-services/guide/index.html

But it doesn't seem to work out because of an env string that cannot be set like so:

```
task createPostgresContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer, dependsOn: pullPostgresImage) {
    group = "docker"
    ext {
        pgContainerName = "demo-db"
        dbName = "demo-db"
        dbPort = 5432
        dbPassword = "kevintan"
    }
    description = 'Creates PostgreSQL container'
    containerName = pgContainerName
    imageId = pullPostgresImage.imageName+":"+pullPostgresImage.tag
    portBindings = ["${dbPort}:5432"]
    env = [
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${dbPassword}",
            "POSTGRES_DB=${dbName}",
    ] as String[]

    onError { e ->
        if (e.class.simpleName in ['BadRequestException', 'ConflictException']) {
            logger.warn 'Container already exists'
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set the env? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I forgot to read the changelogs.

Removed DockerCreateContainer.env, replaced by DockerCreateContainer.envVars